# How to run a .Net Application without installing windows?

Tags: .net, windows, server

I have a .Net application which runs perfectly in Windows 8.1. And what I want to do is run it in a computer but without installing windows. I want to expose my software to other people in a touch screen monitor and if windows runs there, it give the ability to them to access the OS and do several stuff. So isn't there any solution by Microsoft like some server or something, which allows you only to install the .Net framework and run it's application, from something like a console ?
Thank you !

Comment: You might try .NET Micro Framework but that's totally a different thing which won't support your desktop .NET profile. You will have to rewrite much code.

Comment: there is a .net clr for non-window os, it's call .net mono, i think it's only support linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for, is a way to run your application and preventing users from escaping it. This is what is otherwise known as *kiosk mode*. See this article on [How to put a Windows PC into kiosk mode with Assigned Access](http://www.howtogeek.com/173562/how-to-easily-put-a-windows-pc-into-kiosk-mode-with-assigned-access/) for a guide to accomplish this in Windows 8.1.

Comment: Great. Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

**Running applications without .net:**
You always need Windows to run .net applications! So your enduser has to `purchase a License` (or OEM pc) - (There are Linux implementations for .net like [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) but you have to consider several things during devlopment  to emulate correctly...)

**So:** **`You always need a operatingsystem on which is .net installed!`**

**A comment to your *"Server thoughts"*:**
You are able to share your application via a Terminalserver and an RDP-Connection (seamless remote app). But you also need a license (Windows & TerminalServiceCAL's) and some hardware or serviceprovider too.. don't know your budget ;) - y and not to forget: a licensed WindowsClient or some system with a well implemented RDP-Client... (ThinClients)

**What you should look for** or: **What you meant to ask:**
If you want to avoid the user to change several things on a Windows-Computer  you have restict the user by using `GroupPolicies` and a `Security Logic` or/and by implementing `a different shell`. There is also 3rd party software available to restore all cahnges made by a user on every reboot... many ways to rome.. depends on your needs...

Go further here: [Group Policy management for IT pros](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/group-policy-management-for-it-pros)
and here: [Local Users and Groups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785020(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Hello Downvoter! Have you read the anser?????? i tried to describe the situation for the user - thanks for downvoting & not posting a reason - downvoting, posting no comment & not having a better answer ist just foolish

Comment: You should not even attempt to answer such a question posted by a guy who has no idea what's the relationship between .NET and Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I was looking for something more like kiosk mode, which was mentioned in the other answer.